# Android Bitmap.getPixels() returns different data from BufferedImage.getRGB()

Tags: android, bitmap, bufferedimage

I've generated a testing barcode image,

[image: barcode]

http://generator.onbarcode.com/linear.aspx?TYPE=7&DATA=ID%3ao0123456789&UOM=0&X=1&Y=60&LEFT-MARGIN=0&RIGHT-MARGIN=0&TOP-MARGIN=0&BOTTOM-MARGIN=0&RESOLUTION=0&ROTATE=0&BARCODE-WIDTH=0&BARCODE-HEIGHT=0&SHOW-TEXT=true&TEXT-FONT=Arial|9|Regular&TextMargin=6&FORMAT=png&PROCESS-TILDE=false

I saved it locally and tried to load it with a simple java program and print out the first scanline as following:

```
File bmpFile = new File("barcode.bmp");
BufferedImage img;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(bmpFile);
    int[] pixels = img.getRGB(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), null, 0, img.getWidth());
    int w = img.getWidth();
    for (int i = 0; i< w; i++) {
        System.out.print(pixels[i]+", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And then I tried to load the bitmap in an Android app on emulator with following code

```
Bitmap barcode = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.raw.barcode);
Config cfg = globe.getConfig();
int w = barcode.getWidth();

for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    int color = barcode.getPixel(i, 0);
    System.out.print(color+", ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Unbelievably, those two simple application have to totally different scanline data.

*scanline data from Java program:*

-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -1, -1, -16777216, -1, -1, -1, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -1, -1, -16777216, -1, -1, -1, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -1, -1, -16777216, -1, -1, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -1, -16777216, -1, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -1, -1, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -1, -1, -16777216, -1, -1, -1, -1, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -1, -1, -16777216, -1, -1, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -1, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -1, -16777216, -16777216, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,

*Scanline data from Android app*:

-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2170914, -13026247, -16777216, -15197160, -4342083, -7565684, -15197160, -4342083, -1, -2170914, -13026247, -9736853, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -7565684, -16777216, -16777216, -9736853, -1, -1, -1, -1052689, -13026247, -9736853, -1, -1, -1, -1052689, -13026247, -10855078, -1052689, -13026247, -10855078, -1052689, -13026247, -16777216, -16249848, -4342083, -1, -1, -1, -6512996, -16249848, -4342083, -1, -1, -1, -6512996, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -16249848, -5394771, -1, -1052689, -11907766, -10855078, -1, -1, -6512996, -16777216, -16777216, -10855078, -1, -11907766, -10855078, -1, -1, -1, -1, -11907766, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -5394771, -5394771, -16777216, -5394771, -5394771, -16777216, -5394771, -5394771, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -5394771, -5394771, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -11907766, -1, -10855078, -16777216, -16777216, -6512996, -1, -1, -10855078, -16777216, -16777216, -6512996, -5394771, -16249848, -16777216, -11907766, -1052689, -1, -5394771, -16249848, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -6512996, -5394771, -16249848, -16777216, -13026247, -1052689, -10855078, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -13026247, -1052689, -10855078, -13026247, -1052689, -10855078, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -13026247, -1052689, -9736853, -16777216, -16777216, -7565684, -1, -1, -1, -4342083, -16249848, -7565684, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -9736853, -13026247, -2170914, -9736853, -16777216, -16777216, -7565684, -1, -1, -9736853, -16777216, -16777216, -7565684, -4342083, -15197160, -16777216, -14078935, -2170914, -9736853, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -7565684, -3223602, -15197160, -7565684, -3223602, -15197160, -16777216, -14078935, -2170914, -1, -1, -1, -8684165, -14078935, -2170914, -1, -1, -1, -8684165, -16777216, -16777216, -8684165, -1, -1, -1, -3223602, -14078935, -16777216, -16777216, -16777216, -8684165, -3223602, -14078935, -8684165, -3223602, -14078935, -16777216, -15197160, -3223602, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,

It seems to me that the scanline data from java program is more reasonable. In Android app, I've tried to put the bitmap under both *res/drawable/* and *res/raw/*, however, the same scanline data is returned. Can someone enlighten me how this could happen?

Answer (score 1):

To change the type of the image, you can use the below code. The code is tested.

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, opt);
```

But that does not help. I have a similar problem with different numbers (from getPixel and getRGB) on JDK and Android.

However, my code is to compute histograms on the client (android) and the server (JDK). Then they must be compared.

Is the Problem solved?

UPD. The problem at that time was the JPG format.

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading bitmaps from the drawables folder?  I had a problem where on some devices, the bitmaps would be changed slightly in this case.  I solved it by putting the bitmap resource in the raw folder

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are loading the bitmap in 565. Pass a BitmapFactory.Options to decode() and force decoding in ARGB_8888.

Comment: As you suggested, I tried the code snippet below, the variable _cfg_ still has value as **RGB_565** 
                        <br><pre>
                        Options opt = new Options();
                        opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                        Bitmap globe = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.raw.barcode, opt);
                        Config cfg = globe.getConfig(); </pre>